# creating more than 1000 threads using pthread_create()

Tags: c++, posix

I'm trying to create 1000 threads using the `pthread_create()` function.

This is the statement I'm using:

```
for (int i=0 ; i <1000; i++)
{
   retValue = pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, simplethreadFunction, NULL);
}
```

Everytime this for-loop runs does it create a new thread?

This is a simple thing. But I'm unable to understand it.

Comment: Yes it creates 1000 threads, is there anything that makes you think it is not working?

Comment: ok.. but i was told tat the above code is incorrect and i have to pass an array of values to the threadID some thing like this statement`for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
                res = pthread_create(&a_thread[i], NULL, thread_function, NULL);
                
        }

Comment: i'm trying to measure time it takes to create 1000 threads `for (int i=0 ; i <1000; i++)
{
   retValue = pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, simplethreadFunction, NULL);
}` if i use this way to create 1000 threads.. will i get the correct time it takes to create 1000 threads?

Comment: @paddy Yes, that's right. Otherwise, how will you identify the threads? With your current code, all the threads are going to overwrite their IDs and you'll only have one thread ID which was created as last one.

Comment: Note, that some operating system limit could be reached before 1000 threads can be created. You should check retValue and count how many threads actually are created successfully.

Comment: ok i understood wat u said.. but will it affect the time it takes to create 1000 thread wen i dont pass array of values to the thread id? i'm measuring time it takes to create 1000 threads..

Comment: What's the point in measuring something that is unrealistic? But anyway the *only* way to tell is to time both methods and see if there is any difference.

Comment: *"Everytime this for-loop runs does it create a new thread?"* - Maybe this could be answered by looking at the mere name of the function **`pthread_create`**?

Answer (score 5):

> Everytime this for-loop runs does it create a new thread?

Yes, it does.

> This is a simple thing. But I'm unable to understand it.

I will add a few more points:

1. First parameter to the function pthread_create is pointer type to pthread_t. Basically you are passing an address to this function, which this function uses to assign 'something'.

   When this function creates a thread, an 'opaque, unique identifier' for this thread is created and the pointer you passed is made to point to this location, so that you can access it later, if required.
2. If you will pass the same pointer all the 1000 times, you will have access to the unique identifier for only one (the last one) thread created out of all 1000, because each time the previous value will get over written.
3. This unique value is required if you would want to perform further operations on a thread (like joining etc).
4. For details about  this function and other thread related functions you can go though [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_create.txt) and [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).
5. Don't forget to call pthread_exit in your main context, otherwise complete program (including the created threads) might terminate even before all your threads would have finished.

Also regarding the time, this thing might not have any effect on time of creation as far as I think, will just reduce the usability of threads you have created. Also, this time you are calculating is not THE time for creating 1000 threads, will depend on lot of other factors like platform/implementation etc.

Comment: @paddy Since, you seems to be a newcomer to this site, I would like to share this with you - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work [At Others : Consider this as a bad attempt to get some rep :p]